# adding 1 month to the current date in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I cannot find how to add 1 month to the current date in Yii

I've tried

```
$this->toDate = new CDBExpression('NOW()+ INSTANCE 1 MONTH');
```

but it gives me a mysql error

check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 MONTH)' at line 1

is it good to use CDBExpression or is there a better way ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that

```
 $this->toDate = new CDBExpression('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');
```

or simply

```
$this->toDate = new CDBExpression('NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH');
```

Comment: Great !  I dont know where I saw INSTANCE instead of INTERVAL.  Thanks